# Why mangled names found within an exe?

Tags: c++, linker, name-mangling

I have an MS C/C++ statically linked release exe (no debug info on it), that **does not export any symbol**, but when browsing it with a hex viewer I see things like

```
.?AVElxInterface@@
.?AV?$CBufferRefT@H@@
.?AV?$CBufferT@H@@
.?AV?$CBufferRefT@PAVElxInterface@@@@
```

of course they are the mangled names of certain classes/members provided by the internal C++ modules.

why are they there? how can avoid exposing them?

Comment: Most of it is likely RTTI data.

Comment: They are not dynamic_cast<> nor use typeid operator either...
 Is there any way of preventing leaking this info to an exe???

Comment: Are you sure you aren't exporting? Maybe a static library you are linking with is exporting. Maybe someone is using the `__declspec(dllexport)` directive or pragma. To check if you are exporting, use the exe tools provided.

Comment: "completely" sure there's not a single export. I also compiled with /GR- (disable Run-Time Type Information) with the same result; the symbols still make it to the exe.

Comment: Why is this an issue? I doubt exposing your class names to anyone armed with a hex viewer is really endangering your intellectual property...

Comment: @Cody Gray; you are right but what you say has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: /GR- switch. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we6hfdy0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: /GR is on by default. I also tried /GR- with same results

Comment: in gcc you could add the following to CFLAGS: -fno-rtti -fvisibility=hidden ... not sure the msvc equivalent

Comment: I wish I can find something hiding my names on MS land, or even better being able to define those names as I want.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't see any reason to over-hide this data, as it supplies no clue to people who view it on how to utilize these symbols to do something "bad". However, if that's really a huge problem for you, i.e. you are afraid of being sort of reverse-engineered somehow, then you may opt to code obfuscation. For example, [Semantic Designs](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/CppObfuscationExample.html) offer a product for these purposes and claim that it's of high quality. I've never had a chance to try that stuff myself. Keep in mind that it's commercial.

Comment: Of course my issue is related to security, and of course an obfuscator does not solve the problem. It really bugs me a compiler "feature" (what ever it is) exposing my names if I expressly want to by silent. I understand i.e. typeID surely needs a name but in that case I want to have the option to set it myself to what ever I want (even to a null string)

Comment: May I ask why obfuscation does not solve your problem? It was devised to solve exactly problems like yours.

Comment: Because I do not want to add that extra layer of complexity to my project in order to cover a Microsoft "mistake"?. Obfuscation is ok when you have to provide the source code and you do not want the source to be understood. Here we are talking about an exe compiled with a very expensive compiler/linker that is instructed to be silent but it cannot keep its mouth shut...

Comment: I completely agree with you. But it seems you have tight relationship with MS compiler, as others have proposed to use GCC, but you refused. Therefore, if there is really no switch in MS compiler for this, I see 2 possible ways out of this problem (if it is really so urgent). 1) Write a feature request to MS, which is going to be implemented god knows when (if at all). 2) Obfuscate.

Comment: Well my question says "I have an MS C/C++ statically linked release exe"; I just cannot use gcc. Obfuscation is not an option; I'd be forced to obfuscate the whole project (too big, too slow, too nuts) if you just obfuscate the area that publishes the names is like not obfuscating at all as the hacker immediately knows where is the sensitive area. Have you ever used IDA? then you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: You would have to obfuscate only 1 time, exactly before you are ready to build a final release. Anyway, if you want your product to be so secure, then adding this extra layer of security (I'd call it rather than complexity) is worth it.

If you are just given some executable to the sources of which you do not have access, and been told to patch this awful hole, then, unfortunately, you are out of options.

Comment: You are twisting things; 1) Obfuscation does not add security to an exe. 2) Obfuscation is not meant for hiding names within an exe. 3) WTH are you saying? I do not have to patch anything, I have every single line of source code, I'm "compiling" the EXE ...

Comment: 1) and 2) Again I insist, that in your particular case, when symbols are visible from executable, it will provide security to certain extent. 3) That's because you mislead: "I have an MS C/C++ statically linked release exe; I just cannot use gcc." Then: "I have every single line of source code, I'm "compiling" the EXE ...". In other words, your reasoning of why you can't use GCC is confusing.

Comment: 1) & 2) your solution is a patch that gives you a false sense of security. 3) I cannot use GCC because I have a Microsoft Solution all compiled with Microsoft and I do not want to use GCC on it; you know I care about my building chain; can you imagine the number of side effects that just adding GCC on that soup might bring...

Comment: Your situation is a good example why I don't use MS compiler any more and will never come back to it again. I know that it is always a pain to migrate, to rethink something, to invest time in order to tweak something new. However, I believe that in this case this investment might be worth your time (again of course it depends on your deadlines and other things like project manager preferences, etc.). MinGW-w64 is very mature and powerful toolchain. Honestly, if there was no toolchain like that - I don't know, probably I would quit C++ programming, seriously.

Comment: In addition, GCC supports far more features than MS compiler, which means that most likely the migration will be smooth, without a single compilation error, and all you would have to do is to recall and utilize some switches properly. If you'd use a modern build system with cross-compiler support, then it should go even smoother. But in your case, you burn bridges yourself by limiting yourself with such a close bond with MS toolchain and its build system.

Comment: I understand your point here; I'm an old VS user and migrating the project just for some f***ing names makes me really mad; I cannot believe there were not complains on this topic before mine; c'mon... I'll try to see if I find some reference on technet/msdn.